# Power of a point with respect to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

I was reading the power of a circle from this-http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePower.html
  Here they are saying tht the power of A with respect to the circle of radius r is given by $p= AP \times AQ$ 
 but in the next case where they are calculating the power of P w.r.t. that circle they are writing $p=d^2-r^2$ (see at the link). 
 But when I tried to calculate it myself I got $p=d(d-r)$ i.e. 
Power of P(according to the given definition) 
$p=PR\times PO
  =(OP-OR) \times OP
  =(d-r)d
  = d^2-rd$ 
 I'm not getting the value which I should had. [image]

Answer (score 1):

*O* shouldn't be one of your two points. You need to compute $PR \cdot PS$, where $R$ and $S$ are the two points where $OP$ meets the circle. The segment $RS$ is a diameter.

Comment: I have given a image. Please see that ,

Comment: My answer still fits your image. Extend the ray PO until it meets the circle again, at S.

Comment: oh ho ! got it.